# R programming, showing error

Tags: r

Whenever I am trying to load the `tidyverse` package in R it is showing the following error.  How do I fix it?

```
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :    namespace ‘tibble’ 1.3.0 is already
> loaded, but >= 1.3.1 is required
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Comment: Have you tried updating tibble...

Comment: The error says, the package `tidyverse` cannot be loaded because your version of package `tibble` is older than the minimum required `tibble` version. Type `install.packages("tibble")` to upgrade your `tibble`

Comment: Alternatively, I would update all of your packages. If you're in RStudio, there's an option to update all packages.

Comment: Thank you to all,  I have updated the update field in R studio and the problem is solved.